# Usage of JMS to call a API which delivers a message

Tags: jms, jms-topic

I would like to know if using a JMS in the below scenario is feasible or not.
I am adding a feature of calling an API service which will dispatch the emails to the customer.
So i thought of implementing a JMS in my application where i would put the events or messages in the queue and write a listener in the same application which will process the message and call the rest API service call which will dispatch the message to the customers.

My question was is it good to have a JMS in between the rest call and our application ?
Or should i directly call the rest api to dispatch the messages to the customer ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends on the availability and overhead of your rest service.

If you know there will be times that your service will be down, but don't want to impact the process using the API, then JMS queues make since.

Or if you feel the rest service is causing a bottle neck from the API service side and want to queue up the messages somewhere where they can survive an outage of your own, JMS with a provider that supports persistent messages makes since in this case.

Using JMS would also open the door for completely decoupling the two.  Whatever application hosts the rest service could just as easily be converted to pull messages from the JMS queue without a need to make a rest call if that seemed more efficient.

Just a few examples of how you could justify using JMS in this scenario.